# Cakephp Controller isn´t processing form data

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hi I´m new with cakephp (v.1.3). I´m trying to do something simple.

I have two tables: fichas[id,... etc] and labos[id,laboratorio,ficha_id] so "labos" belongs to "fichas". (labos.laboratorio is ENUM field).

I would like to view a "ficha" given labos.id and labos.laboratorio so I´ve included the following code in "home.ctp"

```
<h3>Mostrar Ficha</h3>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ficha',array('action'=>'localiza'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->radio('laboratorio',array('A','B','C'),array('A','B','C')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('label'=>'Numero','type'=>'text')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end("Mostrar");?>
```

Then in "fichas_controller.php" added the following:

```
function localiza(){

    $laboratorio=$this->data['Ficha']['laboratorio'];
    $id=$this->data['Ficha']['id'];
    if(!$id){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Por favor introduzca un valor valido');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

    $this->set('fichas',$this->Ficha->findID($id,$laboratorio));

}
```

Finally in the model "ficha.php" the following:

```
function findID($id=null,$laboratorio=null){
    return $this->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Labo.laboratorio'=>$laboratorio,'Labo.id'=>$id)));
}
```

Obviously the file views/fichas/localiza.ctp exists

The thing is when I press the submit button in the form it just reloads the home.ctp page. Looks like the controller´s code is not being executed because i´ve tried to force the error message that should load the index action changing the if condition to true but the same result. I´ve changed the name of the function in the model expecting an error to ocurr but I get the same result.
I have another two forms in the home.ctp page but calling another actions and models.
One of them its almost identical and it works fine.
I can´t figure out the error.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Marcelo.

Comment: Could you post the HTML generated from home.ctp?

Answer (score 0):

The array key `$this->data['Ficha']` likely doesn't exist. You've created the lowercase "ficha" form, this name should be capitalized, otherwise the data is available in `$this->data['ficha']`. So the form creation call would look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ficha',array('action'=>'localiza'));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug in two ways on Cake

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
debug($this->data);
```

OR

The other PHP ways

```
print_r($this->data);
```

This way, you will know if you are passing the data->params properly.

Why is your model has first charcter in lower-case? It should be

- Fichas
- Labos

Then you can issue a direct find on the controller, if you only want.

$d = $this->Fichas->find('all', array();

Answer (score 0):

You might have added the home.ctp file into another controller. Try adding the controller in the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ficha',array('controller' => 'fichas', 'action'=>'localiza'));?>
```

Hope it helps.